# Jupyter kernel dies when I execute cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'll execute this code and the kernel will die. I get no other warning. I have already tried googling and making sure that my version of Python is up to date.

Here is the code that I execute that crashes the kernel.

```
 # EXECUTE FIRST

# computational imports
from pyomo.environ import *

# plotting imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

# display imports
from IPython.display import display, IFrame
from IPython.core.display import HTML

# for playing videos, customize height and width if desired
# keep a 16:9 ratio, e.g. 960 by 540, or 1280 by 720
def play_video(vid_name, w=640, h=360):
    vid_path = "-"
    return IFrame(vid_path + vid_name + "/index.html", width=w, height=h)
```

Other functions seem to work on the notebook, I can create variables and execute code, but there is something in this code block that is crashing the kernel.

I've removed the video URL; it's an educational video on an introduction to the class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS codes Jupiter extension it is way better.